# Evaluate $\int e^{2\theta} \sin (3\theta)\ d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int e^{2\theta} \sin (3\theta)\ d\theta .$$

I am little stuck as to what I can do after this point. Please tell me if my method overall is flawed:

[image]

Comment: Notice that you have an integral on the right-hand side which is the same as that on the left-hand side, and it's the one unknown in the equation.  So solve the equation for the unknown integral.

Answer (score 3):

**An alternative**:

Work in reverse and try differentiating the expression "to see",

$$(e^{2t}\sin(3t))'=2e^{2t}\sin(3t)+3e^{2t}\cos(3t).$$

There is a similar new term, with a cosine. Have a look at its derivative,

$$(e^{2t}\cos(3t))'=2e^{2t}\cos(3t)-3e^{2t}\sin(3t).$$

Then, forming a suitable linear combination to eliminate the cosine, you get

$$(2e^{2t}\sin(3t)-3e^{2t}\cos(3t))'=13e^{2t}\sin(3t).$$

---

More generally, $e^{ax}\sin/\cos(bx)$ will yield

$$(e^{ax}(a\sin(bx)-b\cos(bx)))'=(a^2+b^2)e^{ax}\sin(bx),\\
(e^{ax}(a\cos(bx)+b\sin(bx)))'=(a^2+b^2)e^{ax}\cos(bx).$$

Answer (score 2):

If you denote $I := \int e^{2 \theta} \sin 3 \theta$, then your computation using integration by parts twice (which is the standard approach, and a reasonable one) says that
$$I = f(\theta) + \frac{9}{4} I$$
for some function $f$ that does not involve an integral. (Perhaps there is a sign error in your formula, but this does not affect the applicability of our method:) Hence by algebra we can simply solve for $I$ (i.e., evaluate the integral) in terms of $f$. (Don't forget to include the general constant, i.e, the "$+ C$", which should appear in the formula for your general antiderivative but does not appear in the above equality because, as usual, we interpret $I$ to be a *family* of functions, all equal up to an overall constant.)

If you're comfortable with complex numbers, one can also evaluate the integral by recalling that $\sin \alpha = \frac{1}{2 i}(e^{i \alpha} - e^{-i \alpha})$ distributing, using that $\int e^{\beta t} dt = \frac{1}{b} e^{\beta t} + C$, and rewriting your expression in real terms.

Answer (score 1):

You  have some mistake:
$$
\int e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta) d\theta=\frac{1}{2}e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta)-\frac{3}{2}\int e^{2\theta}\cos(3\theta) d\theta=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta)-\frac{3}{4} e^{2\theta}\cos(3\theta) -\frac{9}{4}\int e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta) d\theta
$$
so:
$$
\left(1+\frac{9}{4} \right)\int e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta) d\theta=\frac{1}{2}e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta)-\frac{3}{4} e^{2\theta}\cos(3\theta)
$$
and
$$
\int e^{2\theta}\sin(3\theta) d\theta=\frac{e^{2\theta}}{13}\left(2\sin(3\theta)-3\cos(3\theta)\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler to compute with  the complex exponential function: $\;\mathrm e^{2\theta}\sin 3\theta$ is the imaginary part of $\;\mathrm e^{(2+3\mathrm i)\theta}$. So we compute:
\begin{align*}
\int \mathrm e^{(2+3\mathrm i)\theta}\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu\theta&=\frac1{2+3\mathrm i} \mathrm e^{(2+3\mathrm i)\theta}=\frac{2-3\mathrm i}{13} \mathrm e^{(2+3\mathrm i)\theta}\\
&=\frac1{13}\mathrm e^{2\theta}\bigl(2\cos 3\theta+3\sin3\theta+\mathrm i(2\sin3\theta-3\cos 3\theta)\bigr),
\end{align*}
and take the imaginary part of the result:
$$\int\mathrm e^{2\theta}\sin 3\theta\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu\theta=\frac1{13}\mathrm e^{2\theta}(2\sin3\theta-3\cos 3\theta).$$

Comment: I'm in Calculus II. Why would you even bring this method up?

Comment: You've never heard of complex numbers? That is quite standard and avoids integration by parts. And you have two integrals for the price of one.

Comment: @Sunny It's true that this is a standard sort of problem from calc II, but it could also arise in a mechanics or analog electronics class, because the integrand has the form of a damped harmonic oscillator (well, it would if the coefficient $2$ were replaced by a negative number, but that makes little difference here).

Comment: Either way, answers on math.se are often, but need not always be, written for the person who poses the question. You'll find many good answers on the site that treat questions using techniques possibly unknown to respective OPs, but which provide insights that help out other readers with the same question (but who do have the requisite background) or that other people browsing the site may find interesting or useful.

Comment: @Travis Hur visste du att jag var svenska medborgare

Comment: @Sunny I did not know that, why did you think I did?

Answer (score 0):

Observe

$$(e^{at}\sin(bt+\phi))'=e^{at}(a\sin(bt+\phi)+b\cos(bt+\phi))=e^{at}r\sin(bt+\phi+\delta),$$
where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\tan(\delta)=\dfrac ba$.

The derivative of a damped sinusoid is that damped sinusoid with a change in amplitude and in phase.

It suffices to reverse these changes to get

$$\int e^{at}\sin(bt)dt=e^{at}\frac 1r\sin(bt-\delta)=e^{at}\frac 1r(\sin(bt)\frac ar-\cos(bt)\frac br).$$